# WebGL crashes when generating a texture - OutOfMemory

Tags: three.js, textures, webgl, rendering

I currently use Three.js in a bigger web project.
Everything works fine and there is no issue with rendering and so on. The only problem I am running into is kind of specific.

In a part of my project, the user is able to position an image on a 3D-Model through a canvas, which is used as texture. Sometimes, when the user is really fast changing the position via clicks, WebGL stops working.

In Chrome :

> Rats! WebGL hit a Snag - alert

So the user has to reload the page.

Is this actually a **performance issue**? 
If it is, is the only way to reduce the speed of transformations per second? Or is there something like a try/catch thing so it will just perform the transformation, if it will not lead to block WebGL?

I really want to keep this live positioning of the Image on the 3D-Model.

Also I could hide other objects in the scene, so only the object on which the image is positioned will be shown, would that help?

Thank you for your time and answers!

This is the actual error in the console :

```
GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glGenSyncTokenCHROMIUM:
fence sync must be flushed before generating sync token

filename.html:1 WebGL: CONTEXT_LOST_WEBGL: loseContext: context lost
```

The code executed for each click is :

```
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 1024;
canvas.height = 1024;
canvas.style.width = canvas.width + "px";
canvas.style.height = canvas.height + "px";
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

context.save();
context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, x + width / 2, y + height / 2);
context.rotate(angle * TO_RADIANS);
var imgT = new Image();
imgT.src = fotoprintPath + this.id;
context.drawImage(imgT, -width / 2, -height / 2, width, height);
context.restore();

matTexture.map = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
matTexture.map.needsUpdate = true;
```

Does it have something to do with asynchrone function calls, like WebGL has not finished the previous task and so crashes?

In Firefox the browser just crashes. I hope somebody can help with this, or tell me how to avoid it.

**Update
When I restrict the clicks per second is not a satisfying solution. The problem by this solution is, either I have to allow only 1 click per second (which makes positioning very slow) or I use the clicks per second my PC can handle but this causes users of tablets and slow PC's to still recieve the error.

What I really need is a function like this

```
function canPerformTextureTransformation(){
   if(availableMemory >= neededMemory)
       return true;
   else
       return false;
 }
```

But how can I check for the memory that will be needed and the available memory?

Comment: Do you have some code we can test?

Comment: Is the original error by any chance in German? Because the German "WebGL wurde blockiert" error is reported in English as "Rats! WebGL hit a Snag.", which will give you a lot more answers on google as well as better StackOverflow answers. I've personally never encountered "WebGL was blocked",

Comment: Yes, sorry i just tried to translate it.

Comment: You allocate a new ~4Mo texture on each click. At some point your context run out of memory.

Comment: Is there a way to restrict calls, so it will not run out of memory? Like a check for memory, before the actual texture will be allocated. Or is there any other way to transform/scale/rotate the texture?
I also wish to be able to move the texture via drag of the mouse, but this causes even more calls of the function and it will run out of memory more easily. 
So what i really need I guess is a call to check if its possible or not, if not it will just wait. I am not so deep into js so i know how to do that, are there any advices?

Comment: No one? Really need some help with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, which seems to completly solve the problem.

I just **reduced the size** of the applied texture from **1024x1024 to 256x256**

```
canvas.width = 1024; --> canvas.width = 256;
canvas.height = 1024; --> canvas.height = 256;
canvas.style.width = canvas.width + "px";
canvas.style.height = canvas.height + "px";
```

This is not what I searched, but there is no real visible change in the result, so it is an workaround which I will use. By changing this, all operations are much faster.